# Join content of several WordPress categories into new virtual category

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, categories

Lets imagine we have the following categories in WP:

- /shop/jeans/black
- /shop/jeans/blue
- /shop/jeans/white
- /shop/t-shirts/black
- /shop/t-shirts/blue
- /shop/t-shirts/white

What I need is to create virtual categories that can show content from certain given ones, for example:

- /shop/clothes/black

will hold content from /shop/jeans/black and /shop/t-shirts/black showing only black clothes.

I know I can virtually join categories content by custom links like

- /shop/jeans,t-shirts

but it is not useful.

I also know I can use tags. Also I can add content to multiple categories.

All that don't work in my case.

Is there a way to organize categories themselves into categories?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of plug-ins at WP's repository exactly for this need, just search for **custom taxonomy**. I would recommend [Simple Taxonomy](https://github.com/herewithme/simple-taxonomy). This plug-in haven't been updated for more than three years but it seems to be working as expected with WP 4.4.2. It is quite powerful and totally free.